# Create all the json files at a time by getting all the values from a text file using C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, text-files, keyvaluepair

I create a long text file name POI.txt which contain City name at first and then places name of that city. My Text File look like this-

```
Flensburg;Flensburger Brauerei;Flensburg station;Fachhochschule Flensburg;Flens-Arena;Duborg-Skolen;Nordertor
Kiel;Walther Schücking Institute of International Law;Ferdinand Tönnies Society;Zoological Museum of Kiel University
Berlin;Battle of Berlin;Timeline of Berlin;Warschauer Straße;Berlin Brandenburger Tor station;Embassy of the United Kingdom, Berlin
and many many city.........
```

After that I keep the city name in Combobox1 and the places name in Combobox2. So When One city comes in combobox1 it shows all the Places of that city in the 2nd combobox. I create a button after the 2nd Combobox. I use this button to create a json file of a places.

This is my json create method for each place.

```
public void ToJsonForLocation(string CityName,string PoiName)
    {

        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "OnePoiJson");
        string SubfolderName = Path.Combine(folderName, CityName);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SubfolderName);
        string fileName = PoiName + ".json";

        var path = Path.Combine(SubfolderName, fileName);
        var Jpeg_File = new DirectoryInfo(startPath + @"\Image\" + CityName).GetFiles("*.jpg");

        POIData Poi=new POIData();
        Poi.Name = PoiName;
        Poi.Shorttext = new WikiShortText().GetShortText(PoiName);
        Poi.GeoCoordinates = GeosFromString(startPath + @"\Latitude Longitude\" + PoiName + ".txt");
        Poi.Images = new List<string> { Jpeg_File[0].Name };

        //Poi.Images =new List<string> {  string.Format("{0:X}.jpg", new WikiImage().GetImage(PoiName).Image.GetHashCode())};

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Poi,Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path,json);
     }
```

I am calling this method in the main form in this way-

```
  private void JSON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            JSON_Output poi_Json = new JSON_Output();
            poi_Json.ToJsonForLocation(comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text);
    }
```

Now my problem is that with my code, I need to click every places on the 2nd combobox to create a json file for that city.It takes too much time. I want to create all the file at a time. I know I need to create a dictionary to do this. But As I am very new to handle this situation I want to know how to proceed with it.

Comment: `I need to click every places on the 2nd combobox to create a json file for that city` are you saying that right now you have to select one option at a time for comboBox2 and individually create each json by clicking your button, but you wanted to be able to select multiple items from comboBox2 to generate it all at once?

Comment: @Prix. Exaclty. I want that whenever values appears on second combobox it create all files at a time with button click.

Comment: OK, but you want the user to be able to select which entries from the comboBox2 or you want all entries to generate a file or its 1 file with all selected entries? [If you want it to allow for multiple selections](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and)

Comment: @Prix I want that If I select a city like Berlin in combobox 1. Then in combobox 2 there will be appeared Plac1,Place2,Place3.. etc. So all the json file for this places will be created at a time. Same as If I select Munich in Combobox 1 it will create all json file for that city at a time.

Comment: But values should be dependent on combobox 1

Comment: Yes, but what I am asking is IF you want to be able to select the places from comboBox2 or not. If you don't want to select any place from the 2nd comboBox then you could simple read the registered items in a foreach from that comboBox, something like `foreach (var item in comboBox2.Items)`

Comment: @Prix Could you please explain a liitle bit more. For me  making all the json file at a time is the first priority. So it would not be problem if i cannot select any places from second combobox

Comment: @Prix. I tried to write your code. But Could not succedd.